# How to share an opportunity to running user(low level of role) using apex

Tags: apex, opportunity, sharing

I am trying to share an opportunity using apex. Apex running user is having low level of role compared to opportunity owner. How is this possible ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question? Who is the "running user", and what is their relationship in the Role Hierarchy to the Opportunity Owner? Are you experiencing an error?

Comment: Apex runs on user mode when you apply 'with sharing' with sharing rules applies for that particular user. currently logged in user is low level of hierarchy when compared to opportunity owner. Yes, I was facing cross reference id error while sharing opportunity.

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved with changing the class as 'without sharing'.